# Error while converting nvarchar to datetime

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to execute my MSSQL stored procedure from my java program by giving as parameters two dates to have aselection between this two dates. So in java code I proceeded like this:

```
"EXEC [dbo].[MyProcedure] " + "'"+ dateFrom+"'" ,"'"+dateTo"'"
```

I have declared my parameters in sql server procedure like this way : `@collected_date1 datetime, @collected_date2 datetime`.
And I selected the two date like this :

```
SELECT @date1 = Convert(varchar(23),@collected_date1,121)
SELECT @date2= Convert(varchar(23),@collected_date2, 121)
```

However I have this message error : `Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime`

Could you help me please ?
Thank you

Comment: What do the values of `dateFrom` and `dateTo` look like once in the EXEC statement? I assume they are strings representing dates, but what format are those dates? Perhaps the engine can't convert them using the current locale settings and/or date format.

Answer (score 2):

on above statement you declared variable

@collected_date1 datetime,
@collected_date2 datetime

and when you set  you convert data-type to varchar so it give you error

if you want to set into datetime datatype you should use

```
SELECT @date2= Convert(datetime,@collected_date2, 121)  ;
```

Comment: Thank you, it's Ok now with your answer, but I have another probleme with this error :  "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". I give do my date parameters this format "yyyy-mm-dd". Any idea to correct this please. Thanks a lot

Comment: `Convert(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @Month) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @Day)
+ '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @Year))`

Comment: this is another one   `SELECT convert(datetime, @collected_date2+ '00:00:00', 120) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h) `

Comment: `@collected_date1` and `@collected_date2` are already declared as `datetime` values, why would the OP want to convert them to `datetime` again? So `varchar(23)` makes perfect sense, and the issue might be happening at the time of parsing the parameters, i.e. before the stored procedure is actually executed.